# Fastest way to Remove Duplicate Value from a list<> by lambda

Tags: c#, list, c#-4.0, lambda, generic-list

what is fastest way to remove duplicate values from a list.
Assume `List<long> longs = new List<long> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 5 };` So I am interesting in use lambda to remove duplicate and returned : `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`. What is your suggestion?

Comment: how about `longs.Distinct()`?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

The easiest way to get a *new* list would be:

```
List<long> unique = longs.Distinct().ToList();
```

Is that good enough for you, or do you need to mutate the *existing* list? The latter is significantly more long-winded.

Note that [`Distinct()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx) isn't *guaranteed* to preserve the original order, but in the current implementation it will - and that's the most *natural* implementation. See my [Edulinq blog post about `Distinct()`](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/30/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-14-distinct.aspx) for more information.

If you don't need it to be a `List<long>`, you could just keep it as:

```
IEnumerable<long> unique = longs.Distinct();
```

At this point it will go through the de-duping each time you iterate over `unique` though. Whether that's good or not will depend on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks, so I think `longs = longs.Distinct().ToList()` is correct. right?

Comment: @Saeid: So long as nothing else already has a reference to the original list, that should be fine. You need to distinguish between mutating the list itself, and changing the variable to refer to a new list (which is what that code will do).

Comment: If it is important to mutate the same list, couldn't we just say: `var newTmpList = longs.Distinct().ToList(); longs.Clear(); longs.AddRange(newTmpList);`

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Yes, that's a possibility - but it's not a terribly *nice* way of doing it...

Comment: This worked for me.  I'm my case, I needed to update the list, so I just did the following:  `long = long.Distinct().ToList();`

Answer (score 84):

You can use this extension method for enumerables containing more complex types:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> distinctList = sourceList.DistinctBy(x => x.FooName);

public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    var knownKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
    return source.Where(element => knownKeys.Add(keySelector(element)));
}
```

Comment: +1 Excellent answer - the all encompassing answers are always my favorite! This is exactly what I was looking for. I love how there is always that disparity between primitives and complex types. It is almost as bad as learning a new language and only having the #(*%$()*@ useless hello world example! Okay, off my soap box, great answer!

Comment: I also prefer this solution because it uses a lambda as the OP requested in the title (note: Linq's `Distinct()` does not) so it can easily be used on other datatypes without having to implement `Equals`/`GetHashCode` or an `IEqualityComparer`

Comment: Very elegant solution but after ? We have a sourceList and a distinctList.
How can we update the dbSet to reflect changes on the Database ?

Comment: fantastic answer !
and u want to disticts by many keys , just call it multiple times with different key selectors :)

Answer (score 7):

There is Distinct() method. it should works.

```
List<long> longs = new List<long> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 5 };
var distinctList = longs.Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to stick with the original List instead of creating a new one, you can something similar to what the `Distinct()` extension method does internally, i.e. use a HashSet to check for uniqueness:

```
HashSet<long> set = new HashSet<long>(longs.Count);
longs.RemoveAll(x => !set.Add(x));
```

The List class provides this convenient `RemoveAll(predicate)` method that drops all elements not satisfying the condition specified by the predicate. The predicate is a delegate taking a parameter of the list's element type and returning a bool value. The HashSet's `Add()` method returns true only if the set doesn't contain the item yet. Thus by removing any items from the list that can't be added to the set you effectively remove all duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<long> distinctlongs = longs.Distinct().OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple intuitive implementation

```
public static List<PointF> RemoveDuplicates(List<PointF> listPoints)
{
    List<PointF> result = new List<PointF>();

    for (int i = 0; i < listPoints.Count; i++)
    {
        if (!result.Contains(listPoints[i]))
            result.Add(listPoints[i]);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution 1:
`listWithDuplatedItems.Distinct().ToList();`

Solution 2:
`listWithDuplicates.ToHashSet().ToList();`

Answer (score -3):

In-place:

```
    public static void DistinctValues<T>(List<T> list)
    {
        list.Sort();

        int src = 0;
        int dst = 0;
        while (src < list.Count)
        {
            var val = list[src];
            list[dst] = val;

            ++dst;
            while (++src < list.Count && list[src].Equals(val)) ;
        }
        if (dst < list.Count)
        {
            list.RemoveRange(dst, list.Count - dst);
        }
    }
```