# Problems with List<string> when adding strings by variable

Tags: c#, string, list

I wanna do a list without duplicates from a file which have too many lines with identifier, sometimes repeated. When I try using `List<string>.Contains`, it doesn't work. This is, I think, because I'm adding object instead of strings directly.

```
public List<string> obterRelacaoDeBlocos()
{
    List<string> listaDeBlocos = new List<string>();

    foreach(string linhas in arquivos.obterLinhasDoArquivo())
    {
        string[] linhaQuebrada = linhas.Split('|');
        string bloco = linhaQuebrada[1].ToString();

        if (listaDeBlocos.Contains((string)bloco) != true)
        {
            listaDeBlocos.Add( bloco + ":" + listaDeBlocos.Contains(bloco).ToString());
        }
    }
    return listaDeBlocos;
}
```

Comment: Hi... welcome to stackoverflow. You will have the greatest chances of getting answer if you post the question in English.

Comment: A propósito, acima tentei a conversão explícita, jogar a variável por tostring, mas nada resolveu.

Comment: I'm having a hard time reading this because it's a foreign language but `Distinct()` could help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632776/fastest-way-to-remove-duplicate-value-from-a-list-by-lambda

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not in English - this is an **English-only** site - please respect the rules of the site!

Comment: Sorry for using portuguese. This site was recommended by a friend of mine, I didn't take care of its rules (yes, I know I was lazy). But, despite this,@GrantWinney helped me. Thanks for all and next time I'll ask just in English :D

Answer (score 0):

You're appending `":" + listaDeBlocos.Contains(bloco).ToString()` to the string before you add it to the list. That's not going to match when you encounter the same word again, so `Contains` will return `false` and the same word will get added again.

I don't see what point it serves to append `": true"` to the end of each string in the list anyway, so just remove that part and it should work.

```
if (!listaDeBlocos.Contains(bloco))
{
    listaDeBlocos.Add(bloco);
}
```

Since you're only interested in one part of each string, based on how you're splitting, you could rewrite your method using LINQ. This is untested but should work:

```
public List<string> obterRelacaoDeBlocos()
{
   return arquivos.obterLinhasDoArquivo().Select(x => x.Split('|')[1]).Distinct().ToList();
}
```