# Delete duplicates from list

Tags: vb.net

I have the following class :

```
Public Class titlesclass
Public Property Link As String
Public Property Title As String

Public Function Clear()
    Link.Distinct().ToArray()
    Title.Distinct().ToArray()

End Function
End Class
```

And the following code :

```
For Each title As Match In (New Regex(pattern).Matches(content)) 'Since you are only pulling a few strings, I thought a regex would be better.
            Dim letitre As New titlesclass
            letitre.Link = title.Groups("Data").Value
            letitre.Title = title.Groups("Dataa").Value
            lestitres.Add(letitre)
            'tempTitles2.Add(title.Groups("Dataa").Value)
        Next
```

I tried to delete the duplicated strings using the simple way

```
Dim titles2 = lestitres.Distinct().ToArray()
```

And calling the class function :

```
lestitres.Clear()
```

But the both propositions didn't work , i know that i'm missing something very simple but still can't find what it is

Comment: I have bad news .. you are not missing something simple, String.Distinct().ToArray() doesn't do what you think it does, and the class has to implement IComparable for Distinct to know how to compare them https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/321292/how-to-use-the-icomparable-and-the-icomparer-interfaces-in-visual-basic-.net-or-in-visual-basic-2005

Comment: See if you can utilize this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632776/fastest-way-to-remove-duplicate-value-from-a-list-by-lambda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier to use a class that already implements [`IComparable`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/tuple.cs,1806cf6634f5a371):

```
Dim query = From title In Regex.Matches(content, pattern).Cast(Of Match)
            Select Tuple.Create(title.Groups("Data").Value, title.Groups("Dataa").Value)

For Each letitre In query.Distinct
    Debug.Print(letitre.Item1 & ", " & letitre.Item2)
Next
```

or [Anonymous Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/anonymous-types):

```
Dim query = From title In Regex.Matches(content, pattern).Cast(Of Match)
            Select New With {Key .Link = title.Groups("Data").Value, 
                             Key .Title = title.Groups("Dataa").Value}

For Each letitre In query.Distinct
    Debug.Print(letitre.Link & ", " & letitre.Title)
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, Since I notice you are using a `Class`
Here is one option you can do in order to not add duplicate items to your `List` within a class.
I'm using a console Application to write this example, it shouldn't be too hard to understand and convert to a Windows Form Application if need be.

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim titlesClass = New Titles_Class()
    titlesClass.addNewTitle("myTitle") ''adds successfully
    titlesClass.addNewTitle("myTitle") '' doesn't add
End Sub

Public Class Titles_Class
    Private Property Title() As String
    Private Property TitleArray() As List(Of String)

    Public Sub New()
        TitleArray = New List(Of String)()
    End Sub

    Public Sub addNewTitle(title As String)
        Dim added = False
        If Not taken(title) Then
            Me.TitleArray.Add(title)
            added = True
        End If
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", If(added, $"{title} has been added", $"{title} already exists")))
    End Sub

    Private Function taken(item As String) As Boolean
        Dim foundItem As Boolean = False
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(item) Then
            foundItem = Me.TitleArray.Any(Function(c) -1 < c.IndexOf(item))
        End If
        Return foundItem
    End Function

End Class
End Module
```

Another option would be to use a [HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx), It will never add a duplicate item, so even if you add an item with the same value, it wont add it and wont throw an error

```
    Sub Main()
    Dim titlesClass = New HashSet(Of String)
    titlesClass.Add("myTitle") ''adds successfully
    titlesClass.Add("myTitle") '' doesn't add

    For Each title As String In titlesClass
        Console.WriteLine(title)
    Next

End Sub
```

With all of that aside, have you thought about using a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) so that you could have the title as the key and the link as the value, that would be another way you could not have a list (dictionary) contain duplicate items