# Why removing objects from a list with duplicate properties of types double in C# does not give consistent result using different methods?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to find the quickest way to remove duplicate entries in a list.

My list contains objects which have properties `X` and `Y` which are both of type `double`.
I need to remove any objects which contain the same `X` and `Y` values.
My first attempt is very slow.
It will take a list that contains 81403 objects and spit out a new list with 25900 but it takes over a minute to run. Had this run quickly I would have compared the difference in order to add some rounding but it's too slow.

```
private List<DelaunayPoint> DeleteDuplicatesSlowWay(List<DelaunayPoint> points)
{
    List<DelaunayPoint> distinctPoints = new();
    int i = 0;
    foreach (DelaunayPoint p in points)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            distinctPoints.Add(p);
        }
        else
        {
            if (distinctPoints.Any(pnt => pnt.X == p.X) == false ||
                distinctPoints.Any(pnt => pnt.Y == p.Y) == false)
            {
                distinctPoints.Add(p);
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    return distinctPoints;
}
```

The following method will take the same list of 81403 objects but it will spit out a list containing 73385 objects, however, it takes less than a second to run.

```
private List<DelaunayPoint> DeleteDuplicatesFast(List<DelaunayPoint> points)
{
    return points
        .GroupBy(p => new { p.X, p.Y })
        .Select(output => output.First())
        .ToList();
}
```

Why do the above two methods give different results?

Assuming the difference is a rounding error between the two methods, how can I add rounding to the second `DeleteDuplicatesFast` method so I can compare the two?

I would need any rounding to not apply the rounding to the output list.

Comment: The quickest way to remove duplicates would be to not add them in the first place. I suggest overriding `GetHashCode()` and `Equals(obj)` on `DelaunayPoint`, and then using a `HashSet<DelaunayPoint>` instead of a `List<DelaunayPoint>`.

Comment: I'm not sure `if (distinctPoints.Any(pnt => pnt.X == p.X) == false || distinctPoints.Any(pnt => pnt.Y == p.Y) == false)` does what you might think. It seems to me that it would consider `{1,2}` and `{1,3}` to be duplicates. You might want `&&` instead of `||`. `List` is a terrible container to use that way too, the cost of repeated lookups is high. `HashSet` would probably be much better and it only contains unique elements. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-5.0

Comment: To add to @RetiredNinja's comment: Using two `Any()` is false anyway, as this compares the  Xs and Ys belonging to different points in `distinctPoints`. You would have to write `if(!Any(pnt => pnt.X == p.X && pnt.Y == p.Y))` in a single lambda to make it work correctly. But this is slow as it has a time complexity of **O(n^2)**. The second, faster approach is correct.

Comment: AHhh, I can't believe I missed that double `Any` error. I've just checked writing it as `if (distinctPoints.Any(pnt => pnt.X == p.X && pnt.Y == p.Y) == false)` and I now get the same answer as the second method, still slow as expected, but mystery solved so thanks for your help.
Does anyone know how I can add some tolerance to the second method to remove objects that have similar X and Y values? I will also look into  `GetHashCode()` and `Equals(obj)` overrides. I've never used them so thanks for the advice.

Comment: What is this `DelaunayPoint`? A struct, a value object, a class?

Comment: It's a class...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to Remove Duplicate Value from a list<> by lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632776/fastest-way-to-remove-duplicate-value-from-a-list-by-lambda) and [remove duplicate items from list in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44680799/remove-duplicate-items-from-list-in-c-sharp) and [Remove duplicates in the list using linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606679/remove-duplicates-in-the-list-using-linq) and [Remove duplicates from a List<T> in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752/remove-duplicates-from-a-listt-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Note: if you cannot (or do not want to) change the `DelaunayPoint` class or structure, you  can initialize the `HashSet<T>` and pass it a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>`: See: [HashSet<T>(IEqualityComparer<T>)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_HashSet_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer__0__).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the first part of your question: points are only equal if both their X and Y values are equal. You're testing for *either* X or Y being equal.

About the filtering of duplicates. The fastest way is to make your `DelaunayPoint` class implement `IEquatable<DelaunayPoint>` and then add the collection to a `HashSet`:

```cs
class DelaunayPoint : IEquatable<DelaunayPoint>
{
    public DelaunayPoint(double x, double y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
    public double X { get;  }
    public double Y { get;  }

    public bool Equals(DelaunayPoint other)
    {
        return other != null && this.X == other.X && this.Y == other.Y;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return System.HashCode.Combine(X,Y);
    }
}
```

```cs
var set = new HashSet<DelaunayPoint>(points);
```

Now `set` contains distinct points. I tested it to be approx. 7 times faster than `GroupBy`.

Comment: This is great, works really well. I was hoping I could modify it as follows `return other != null && Math.Abs(this.X - other.X) < minTriangleSize && Math.Abs(this.Y - other.Y) < minTriangleSize;` to add my tolerance but it doesn't change the result.

Comment: upvoted, I'll hold off accepting the answer for now to see if anyone can comment on the tolerance part.

Comment: That's because you should change `GetHashCode()` accordingly, i.e. it should round the `X` and `Y` values to make their precision less than `minTriangleSize`.

Comment: But in fact, chances are this can't be solved by simple equality. You want points to be equal if they're close enough to one another. But if point A is "close" to B and B is "close" to C that doesn't necessarily mean that A is "close" to C. Yet, simple equality would say A = B = C (when evaluated in that order) while you'd want it to decide A != C. Even rounding X and Y may not be correct. It depends on the exact problem. Rounding in fact "snaps" your points to a grid of `minTriangleSize`-spaced nodes. If that's OK for you, this simple equality approach may suffice.

Comment: I now remember having seen a similar problem some years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37734601/861716